# PowerShell - DataGridView options

Tags: sql, winforms, powershell, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I am stumped, so I am hoping someone could give me some help here. I am trying to create a Windows Form using PrimalForms Community Edition 2011, that utilizes a DataGridView. I was able to get one created using the following (shamelessly stolen from http://sev17.com/2009/08/02/building-powershell-guis-with-primal-forms/):

```
endregion Generated Form Objects
$bindingSource1 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource
$dataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$serverName = “myserver.com”
$databaseName = “myDB”
$query = ‘select * from tblPotConflicts’
#———————————————-
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#———————————————-
#Provide Custom Code for events specified in PrimalForms.
$Form1_Load=
{
$dataGridView1.DataSource = $bindingSource1
$connString = “Server=$serverName;Database=$databaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;”
$dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ($query,$connString)
$commandBuilder = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder $dataAdapter
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$dataAdapter.fill($dt)

$bindingSource1.DataSource = $dt

$dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns([System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode]::AllCellsExceptHeader)
}
```

This works excellently with creating the binding for the DataGridView, as you can't actually do that [as far as I can tell at least] within PrimalForms itself. What I am curious about is:

1. Can you Omit any columns from the DataGridView? I have a few columns that I would rather hide from the end-users if at all possible, and just manipulate them programmatically behind the scenes. I am no great shakes at SQL, so it is very possible this is something super basic and easy.
2. I have one column that I would like to make act as a ComboBox. I see that in C# they have a choice of column type DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, but I don't know how I can set that up in PowerShell. Does anyone hopefully have any suggestions/solutions on that?

Thank you in advance for any help/insight/suggestions you may be able to offer here.

Comment: For point 1 just replace the `*` in the sql query with just the names of columns wanted separed by comma.

Comment: Doing some more research it seems I can also use `$dataGridView1.Columns["MyColumn"].Visible = $False` I will give both a try when I get a chance. Edit - Your's worked, mine did not. Thanks! For some reason, I didn't think the query was determining which fields were being shown, but the binding of the DataGridView to the table. Thank you! Now, just need question 2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Primal forms, but I think I understand what you're after.  I do a rough approximation of that here:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Select-FromGridView-521a56d8

using Powershell's native out-gridview.  Basically I created a new collection of custom objects from the original objects  that's used for display in the gridview, tied together by the array index numbers the objects in the original array.  Then the Index property from objects selected from the grid is taken back to the original object array to get the objects that will be used for further processing.

If that helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I don't have PowerShell 3.0 in my environment yet, but that isn't quite what I need I believe. WinForms already gives you access to both the combobox object and the datagridviewcomboboxcell object. I believe I will have to work within those to get it going.  Your solution is a pretty cool trick, that I will use once I can get 3.0 in my environment for some of my other scripts though!

Comment: The point wasn't PS 3.0 bits, but the use of a secondary collection  of disposable custom objects used to populate the gridview, so that you can choose to display only selected properties, but still have all the original properties to use "behind the scenes".

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding something here - are you suggesting this as an alternative to the form? If so I should explain that my form is more than just the DataGridView, having multiple tabs, etc. If that isn't what you're suggesting, I am still confused on how I would use this in the middle of the DataGridView to populate just one column? Sorry, I'm not trying to be dense here, but I am confused.

Comment: It's not an alternative to the forms, it's a method of selectively populating information into the forms.  Start with your original collection of objects.  From that, create a collectoin of custom objects with just the properties you want to display.  Use that to populate your gridview.  Write your code to take the custom object selected from the gridview and go back to the original object array  and find the object it was created from. Now you have the original object with all it's properties and methods.